# Multiple instances of Images when Pi Camera is triggered

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have some code that when the PIR Sensor is triggered the camera takes one single images and uploads it to Azure blob storage, taking one single photo is not sufficient but I can't get the Program to take multiple images when the camera is triggered.

```
from gpiozero import MotionSensor
from picamera import PiCamera
from datetime import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings

camera = PiCamera()
pir = MotionSensor()
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='YOURACCOUNT', account_key='YOURKEY')

while True:
  pir.wait_for_motion()
  filename = "pircam-" +  datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.jpg")
  camera.capture(filename)
  pir.wait_for_no_motion()
  block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
  'YOURCONTAINER',
  filename,
  filename,
  content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='image/jpeg'))
```

The Expected results should be the camera taking multiple still images instead of one single still image.

Comment: between `wait_for_motion` and `wait_for_no_motion` you create only one image so you can't get more images. You would have to create different loop - probably without `wait_for_no_motion` which stops your current loop.

Answer (score 0):

The images are saved to files named with a timestamp to the nearest second. If the images are taken in the same second, the filenames will be the same and there will be only one result file. You need to make the filenames different - e.g. use the nearest millisecond.

Comment: That won't solve the problem it's still only taking one still image each time its activated, I want it to take multiple images each time its activated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but `pir.wait_for_no_motion()` stops your loop after first image so you can't get more images. You would have to use `pir.motion_detected` to test if you have to take picture

```
while True:
  if pir.motion_detected:
      filename = "pircam-" +  datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.%s.jpg")
      camera.capture(filename)
      block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(...)
```

I wrote this based on [GPIO_Zero_Cheatsheet.pdf](https://static.raspberrypi.org/files/education/posters/GPIO_Zero_Cheatsheet.pdf)